# Merging 2 simple queries to one query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a simple senario where I am executind 2 queries
first to get an ID from a table

And then using this ID to access information from second table.

```
SELECT ID
FROM TEST_1
WHERE name = 'Example 1'

Select *
FROM TEST_2
WHERE Parent_ID = %ID retrived from the above query%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IN` (if subquery returns more than 1 ID) or `=` (if subquery returns only 1 ID):

```
Select *
FROM TEST_2
WHERE Parent_ID = (SELECT ID FROM TEST_1 WHERE name = 'Example 1')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have something like this: just placeyour 1st query in the where clause

```
Select *
FROM TEST_2
WHERE Parent_ID = (SELECT ID
FROM TEST_1
WHERE name = 'Example 1')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
SELECT TEST_2.*
    FROM TEST_1
    INNER JOIN TEST_2 ON TEST_2.Parent_ID = TEST_1.ID
    WHERE TEST_1.name = 'Example 1'
```